# PHP functions within WordPress widget function/class

Tags: php, oop, wordpress, class, widget

I'm running WordPress 3.1.3, and am looking to create a sidebar widget which *more-or-less* counts down to a recurring event.  I've got the underlying PHP code for the countdown working in a standalone script, but where I'm having trouble is actually "widget-izing" the code, **because it contains references to other functions.**

Here's a distilled version of what I have (not including the required plugin header, *etc.*):

```
add_action("widgets_init", array('LMC_countdown', 'register'));

class LMC_countdown extends WP_Widget {

  function control(){
    echo "This widget doesn't need a control panel in WordPress right now.";
    # In all likelihood, that'll be a separate issue for later. :)
  }
  function widget($args){
    echo $args['before_widget'];
      # //////////////////// BEGIN MAIN WIDGET FUNCTION //////////////////// 
      $year = date("Y",$today);
      echo "<div id=\"sidebar-countdown\">";
        /* ...
           quite a bit of additional PHP logic here, but boils down to:
        */
        echo countdownTo(findEventStart($year));
      echo "</div>";
      # //////////////////// END MAIN WIDGET FUNCTION ////////////////////
    echo $args['after_widget'];
  }
  function register(){
    register_sidebar_widget('LMC Countdown', array('LMC_countdown', 'widget'));
    register_widget_control('LMC Countdown', array('LMC_countdown', 'control'));
  }

} # end class LMC_countdown
```

The issue, of course, is that `countdownTo()` and `findEventStart()` are custom functions which "support" the main widget action, which themselves call a few other "supporting functions."  Wherever I've tried putting these supporting functions — whether in the class after `register()` or within the `widget()` function itself — I keep getting errors that the first of these functions is undefined.

I got most of my structural code for the widget from tutorials and "Hello world" examples, but none are robust enough to have PHP functions nestled within them.  So where should I be putting these "supporting functions" and how should I be calling them within the widget?  **Thanks in advance for your help.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Place those two functions **below** the class. Then they are available inside the class as well.

```
  ...
  }

} # end class LMC_countdown


function countdownTo() {
  ...
```

You have written them a global functions, so they belong outside the class. They will be available to your widget and any other plugin / script. So it's a good idea you prefix their names as well with `LMC_`.

Another way you could do is to add them into the class. All of the class's functions are accesible via `$this` inside the class:

```
class LMC_countdown extends WP_Widget {
  # private functions
  private function countdownTo() {
    ...
  }
  private function findEventStart($year) {
    ...
  }
  ...
  # wp widget functions
  function widget($args){
    ...
    echo $this->countdownTo($this->findEventStart($year));
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: How would I go about making these functions non-global such that they exist wholly within the `LMC_countdown` class?

Comment: That does work, too. Add them as class functions and then access them via `$this`, like `$this->countdownTo()`. But do not place it inside another function of the class, just in the class, e.g. at the beginning of the class.

Comment: @Tim Parent: Added an example for your own class functions and how to call them.

Comment: It seems the `$this->foo()` notation doesn't work within the conditions of `if()` statements, though.

Comment: No idea what you mean. They work like any other function, so you can use them inside `if()` statements or any other expression. Check with `var_dump` if the function returns what you expect.